# Передать значение из Combobox в scrolledtext

Tags: python, tkinter

Как мне передать значение из `Combobox floorPaceNum["values"]`
в `comment = scrolledtext_ScrolledText`
при нажатии `button_enter = Button` ?
Спасибо

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
from tkinter import scrolledtext  
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk

login1 = str("")
password1 = str("")
def clicked():
    login = str(login_enter.get())
    password = str(password_enter.get())    
    if login == login1 and password == password1:
        window.destroy()
        storage()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning('Kļūda', 'Nepareizs logins un/vai parole') 

window = Tk()
window.title("storage")
window.title("storage")
window.geometry("250x100")
login_name = Label(window, text="Login")
login_name.grid(column=0, row=0)
login_enter = Entry(window, width=20)
login_enter.grid(column=1, row=0)
password_name = Label(window, text="Parole", width = 10)
password_name.grid(column=0, row=1)
password_enter = Entry(window, width=20, show="*")
password_enter.grid(column=1, row=1)
button_enter = Button(window, text="Pieslēgties", command=clicked, width=15)  
button_enter.grid(column=1, row=3) 


def storage():
    storage = Tk()
    storage.title("Warehouse storage")
    storage.geometry("600x250")
    fFloor = open("test.txt", "r")
    a = fFloor.read()
    fFloor.close()
    a = a.split("\n")
    floor = []
    for i in a:
        if i[6:7] not in floor:
            floor.append(i[6:7])    
    floor.sort()        
    sektorF = open("test.txt", "r")
    sektorA = sektorF.read()
    sektorF.close()
    sektorA = sektorA.split("\n")
    sektor = []
    for i in sektorA:
        if i[1:2] not in sektor:
            sektor.append(i[1:2])
    sektor.sort()   
    def addcom():
        Add = floorPlaceNum.get()
        print(Add)
    def storageF():
        flour_ = floorNum_list.get()
        sektor_ = sektorNum.get()
        place = open("test.txt", "r")
        placeF = place.read()
        place.close()
        placeF = placeF.split("\n")
        placeB = []
        while True:         
            for i in placeF:
                if flour_ == "":
                    if i[1:2] == sektor_:
                        placeB.append(i)
                if sektor_ == "" and flour_ == "" and i not in placeB:
                    placeB.append(i)    
                if sektor_ == "":
                    if i[6:7] == flour_:
                        placeB.append(i)
                if i[6:7] == flour_ and i[1:2] == sektor_:
                    placeB.append(i)
            break   
        placeB.sort()   
        floorPlaceNum["values"] = placeB        

    sektorName = Label(storage, text="Sektors")
    sektorName.grid(column=0, row=0)
    sektorNum = Combobox(storage)
    sektorNum.current()
    sektorNum.grid(column=0, row=1)
    sektorNum["values"] = sektor

    floorNum = Label(storage, text="Stāvs")     
    floorNum.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    floorNum_list = Combobox(storage)   
    floorNum_list.current()
    floorNum_list.grid(column=1, row=1) 
    floorNum_list["values"] = floor     
    floorPlace = Label(storage, text="Vieta")
    floorPlace.grid(column=2, row=0)
    floorPlaceNum = Combobox(storage)       
    floorPlaceNum.current()
    floorPlaceNum.grid(column=2, row=1)
    commentText = Label(storage, text="komentāri")
    commentText.grid(column=0, row=2)
    button_enter = Button(storage, text="Pievienot", command=addcom, width=15)
    comment = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(storage, width=20, height=5)
    comment.grid(column=0, row=3)
    buttonPlaceSearch = Button(storage, text="Meklēt", command=storageF, width=15)
    buttonPlaceSearch.grid(column=3, row=1)


    button_enter.grid(column=0, row=4)

    storage.mainloop()  


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёте метод нажатия на кнопку:

```
def button_event_listener(event):
    value = floorPlaceNum.get()
    comment.insert(window.END,str(value))
```

А дальше вешаете событие на кнопку:

```
storage.bind('<Button-1>', button_event_listener) 
//где <Button-1> - левая кнопка мыши
//<Button-3> - правая кнопка мыши
//<Motion> - Движение мышью..... и тд.
```

Ещё проще при создании кнопки

```
btn = Button(text="Click Me", background="#555", foreground="#ccc",
             padx="20", pady="8", font="16", command=button_event_listener)
btn.pack()
```

Прочитайте для ознакомления: 
https://pythonbasics.org/tkinter-button/

---

И примеры ScrolledText: 
https://programtalk.com/python-examples/tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText/

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, но немного изменил строку
value = floorPlaceNum.get()
  comment.insert(END, str(value) + "\n")

Comment: @ДенисТимофеев Пожалуйста, если сообщение было полезным поставьте галочку) и на будущее почитайте что такое Class в Python, будет лучше и легче тестировать и отлаживать программы такого рода.

Comment: Поставил ☺ и спасибо за совет